Convert the following address sum function to optimized assembly via both memory and storage. Slots are dynamic
I'm looking to convert the entire function getCurrentSupply() to assembly code as the potential gas savings in this use case are significant. Note that everything should be within a single assembly{} block.
I'm currently doing research on it and will eventually figure it out, but in case anyone with lower-level Yul/Solidity knowledge can answer before I can, here it is:
contract ReflectedAssembly {

    uint256 internal _rTotal; // do not assume storage slot of zero
    uint256 internal _tTotal; // do not assume storage slot of one

    mapping(address => uint256) internal _rOwned;
    mapping(address => uint256) internal _tOwned;

    address[] internal _rExcluded; // array is dynamic, NOT a fixed length

    constructor() {
        _rExcluded = [address(1), address(3332), address(201921), address(99999)];
        _tTotal = 100000000;
        _rTotal = (type(uint).max - (type(uint).max % _tTotal)); 
        _rOwned[address(1)] = _rTotal;
    }


    function _getCurrentSupply() internal view returns (uint rSupply, uint tSupply) {
        address[] memory rExcludedMemory = _rExcluded;
        (rSupply, tSupply) = _getCurrentSupplyMemory(rExcludedMemory);

        // (rSupply, tSupply) = _getCurrentSupplyAssemblyMemory(rExcludedMemory);
        // (rSupply, tSupply) = _getCurrentSupplyAssemblyStorage();
    }

    // The function to convert to assembly
    function _getCurrentSupplyMemory(address[] memory rExcludedMemory) internal view returns (uint rSupply, uint tSupply) {  unchecked  {

        (rSupply, tSupply) = (_rTotal, _tTotal);

        uint len = rExcludedMemory.length; 
        uint rOwnedAcc; 
        uint tOwnedAcc; 
        address account; 
        
        for (uint i; i < len; i++) { 
            account = rExcludedMemory[i];
            (rOwnedAcc, tOwnedAcc) = (_rOwned[account], _tOwned[account]);
            if (rOwnedAcc > rSupply || tOwnedAcc > tSupply) { return (_rTotal, _tTotal); }
            rSupply -= rOwnedAcc; 
            tSupply -= tOwnedAcc;
        }
        return (rSupply < (_rTotal / _tTotal)) ? (_rTotal, _tTotal) : (rSupply, tSupply);
    }}

    // Assembly version A (memory)
    function _getCurrentSupplyAssemblyMemory(address[] memory rExcludedMemory) internal view returns (uint rSupply, uint tSupply) {
        assembly { 
            
        }
    }

    // Assembly version B (storage)
    function _getCurrentSupplyAssemblyStorage() internal view returns (uint rSupply, uint tSupply) {

        assembly {
            rSupply := sload(_rTotal.slot)  // _rTotal and _tTotal are uint256 so they occupy a whole storage slot
            tSupply := sload(_tTotal.slot)  // _rTotal and _tTotal cannot be immutable

            // etc

        }
    }
}


I've creating a working version that avoids the 'unreachable code' error, but it doesn't seem to be much, if at all , faster than regular solidity:
function _getCurrentSupplyAssembly() internal view returns (uint retval_R, uint retval_T /* uint rSupply, uint tSupply */) {

    address[] memory rExcludedMemory = _rExcluded;
    assembly { 

        let earlyBreak 

        let __rTotal := sload(_rTotal.slot)             // rTotal and tTotal are both uint256 so they occupy 1 slot
        let __tTotal := sload(_tTotal.slot)             

        let rSupply := __rTotal                         // (rSupply, tSupply) = (_rTotal, tTotal);
        let tSupply := __tTotal
    
        let len := mload(rExcludedMemory)               // uint len = rExcludedMemory.length;
        let rOwnedAcc                                   // uint rOwnedAcc;
        let tOwnedAcc                                   // uint tOwnedAcc;
        // let account                                     // address account;

        for { let i } lt(i,len) { i := add(i,1) } {
            /*
            account := mload(                           // account = rExcludedMemory[i];
                add(
                    add(rExcludedMemory, 0x20),         // start from one word level down: if 0x80: start at 0xA0
                    mul(i, 0x20)                        // if i is zero: (0 * 0x20) is 0x00, if i is 1: (1 * 0x20) is 0x20 and so on
                )                                       // (0xA0 + 0x00) is 0xA0, (0xA0 + 0x20) is 0xC0 and so on
            )                                           // mload(0xA0): load the value at memory 0xA0
            */

            mstore(
                0x00, 
                mload(add(
                    add(rExcludedMemory, 0x20), mul(i, 0x20)                   
                ))       
            )                                           // store account in word 0x00 (scratch space) (32 bytes)

            mstore(0x20, _rOwned.slot)                  // store rOwned mapping slot in word 0x20 (scratch space) (next 32 bytes)
            rOwnedAcc := sload(keccak256(0x00, 0x40))   // rOwnedAcc = _rOwned[account]

            mstore(0x20, _tOwned.slot)                  // store tOwned mapping slot in word 0x20 (overwrite rOwned mapping slot)
            tOwnedAcc := sload(keccak256(0x00, 0x40))   // tOwnedAcc = _tOwned[account]

            // if (rOwnedAcc > rSupply || tOwnedAcc > tSupply) { return (_rTotal, _tTotal); }

            if gt(rOwnedAcc, rSupply) {                 // exit loop instantly
                earlyBreak := 2
                break
            }
            if gt(tOwnedAcc, tSupply) {                 // exit loop instantly
                earlyBreak := 2
                break                             
            }

            rSupply := sub(rSupply, rOwnedAcc)          // rSupply -= rOwnedAcc; 
            tSupply := sub(tSupply, tOwnedAcc)          // tSupply -= tOwnedAcc;

        } // end for

        // `break` instantly jumps here

        /*
            if (rSupply < (_rTotal / _tTotal)) { 
                return (_rTotal, _tTotal);
            }
            return (rSupply, tSupply);
        */

        if lt(earlyBreak, 2) { // we didn't break early
            if lt(rSupply, div(__rTotal, __tTotal)) { earlyBreak := 1 }                                         
        }

        /// NOTE: We avoid explicitly returning from assembly so as to avoid the mysterious 
        // "unreachable code" error that arises when returning from an inherited assembly function

        switch earlyBreak
        case 2 {                
            retval_R := __rTotal        // if (rOwnedAcc > rSupply || tOwnedAcc > tSupply) { return (_rTotal, _tTotal); }
            retval_T := __tTotal
        }
        case 1 {
            retval_R := __rTotal        // if (rSupply < (_rTotal / _tTotal)) { return (_rTotal, _tTotal); }
            retval_T := __tTotal
        }
        default {
            retval_R := rSupply         // return (rSupply, tSupply)
            retval_T := tSupply
        }

        mstore(0x00,0x00)               // clear memory (best practice)
        mstore(0x20,0x00)
        }
    }


Edit: some optimizations, minor gas improvements
// 26883 (example base)
// 26114
// 26096
// 26028
// 26026
// 25987
// 25965
// 25956

function _getCurrentSupplyAssembly() internal view returns (uint retval_R, uint retval_T /* uint rSupply, uint tSupply */) {

    address[] memory rExcluded = _rExcluded;
    assembly { 

    let earlyBreak 

    let __rTotal := sload(_rTotal.slot)             // rTotal and tTotal are both uint256 so they occupy 1 slot
    let __tTotal := sload(_tTotal.slot)             

    let rSupply := __rTotal                         // (rSupply, tSupply) = (_rTotal, tTotal);
    let tSupply := __tTotal

    let n := mload(rExcluded)                       
    let end := add(add(rExcluded, 0x20), shl(5, n)) // uint len = rExcludedMemory.length;

    for { let i := add(rExcluded, 0x20) } iszero(eq(i,end)) { i := add(i, 0x20) } {

        mstore(0x00, mload(i))                      // store account in word 0x00 (scratch space) (32 bytes)

        mstore(0x20, _rOwned.slot)                      // store rOwned mapping slot in word 0x20 (scratch space) (next 32 bytes)
        let rOwnedAcc := sload(keccak256(0x00, 0x40))   // rOwnedAcc = _rOwned[account]

        mstore(0x20, _tOwned.slot)                      // store tOwned mapping slot in word 0x20 (overwrite rOwned mapping slot)
        let tOwnedAcc := sload(keccak256(0x00, 0x40))   // tOwnedAcc = _tOwned[account]

        if gt(rOwnedAcc, rSupply) {                 // if (rOwnedAcc > rSupply || tOwnedAcc > tSupply) { return (_rTotal, _tTotal); }
            earlyBreak := 1
            break
        }
        if gt(tOwnedAcc, tSupply) {                 // exit loop instantly
            earlyBreak := 1
            break                             
        }

        rSupply := sub(rSupply, rOwnedAcc)          // rSupply -= rOwnedAcc; 
        tSupply := sub(tSupply, tOwnedAcc)          // tSupply -= tOwnedAcc;

    } // end for

    // `break` instantly jumps here

    /*
        if (rSupply < (_rTotal / _tTotal)) { 
            return (_rTotal, _tTotal);
        }
        return (rSupply, tSupply);
    */

    if iszero(earlyBreak) { // we didn't break early
        if lt(rSupply, div(__rTotal, __tTotal)) { earlyBreak := 1 }                                         
    }

    /// NOTE: We avoid explicitly returning from assembly so as to avoid the mysterious 
    // "unreachable code" error that arises when returning from an inherited assembly function

    switch earlyBreak
    case 1 {                
        retval_R := __rTotal        // if (rOwnedAcc > rSupply || tOwnedAcc > tSupply) { return (_rTotal, _tTotal); }
        retval_T := __tTotal        // if (rSupply < (_rTotal / _tTotal)) { return (_rTotal, _tTotal); }
    }                               // case 0.5 also returns rTotal, tTotal
    default {
        retval_R := rSupply         // return (rSupply, tSupply)
        retval_T := tSupply
    }

    mstore(0x00,0x00)               // clear memory (best practice)
    mstore(0x20,0x00)
    }
}

